# instrinsicContentSize issue with images

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am trying to render a view as an image, however, I've noticed that intrinsicConntentSize's height value incorporates the original height of an image in the view I am trying to render, despite it being scaled down.

For example. If I have an image with 4,000px height, but it is shown in the view as ~400px, the intrinsicContentSize will still consider it to have 4,000 pixels, meaning the image of the view generated by the extension is gigantic in height.

How could I fix the intrinsicContentSize calculation or modify the image in a way that doesn't create a gigantic output image?

The image in a view:

```
Image(uiImage: data.postPic)
    .resizable()
    .scaledToFit()
    .frame(maxWidth: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
```

The extension:

```swift
extension View {
    var asImage: UIImage {
        let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: self.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top))
        let view = controller.view
        let targetSize = controller.view.intrinsicContentSize
        print(targetSize)
        view?.bounds = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: targetSize)
        view?.backgroundColor = .clear

        let format = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat()
        format.scale = 3
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: targetSize, format: format)
        return renderer.image { _ in
            view?.drawHierarchy(in: controller.view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Specifying a height for the image fixed this;

```
let aspectRatio = data.postPic.size.width / data.postPic.size.height
                    let calculatedHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / aspectRatio

                    Image(uiImage: data.postPic)
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: calculatedHeight)
```